# Dual View and different monitor frequencies

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I have Nvidia GeForce GTX 760 Ti graphic card. And I have 2 monitor: 60 hz BenQ monitor which is overclocked to 77 hz and AverMedia LGP. When I'm playing a game (Usualy CS because here is every 10 hz unreal difference...) at 77 hz on my main monitor, I also want to record it via the AverMedia LGP. But here is the problem: when I playing at 77 hz, the video from AV LGP is like slow-motion, so I must output to AverMedia LGP only 60 hz, but I want 77 hz to my main monitor. Is that possilbe to do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Re-define?  the game plays fine at the 77 ?  When recording the game with the software everything seems to be going along fine?  but the video created and only that video you made, when played back after the recording seems to be in slow motion?

Comment: @Psycogeek yes, the card is maximum for 60 fps, so when u give it 77 hz it will create a slow-motion, which I dont want.

Comment: If all frames are present, you can just alter the FPS the file reports, probably without even re-encoding the video.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with recording cards, you have to play at the same fps as you record, otherwise there will be a fps disparity. However, that doesn't mean you need to play in 60 fps. Unless you are streaming, I would recommend taking the 77fps video after recording and forcing it to 60 fps in adobe premiere or any other video editing program.

Comment: No, its 60 fps video, but its in "slow-motion" due to more frames. I just need to one source 77 hz and to the recording card 60 hz.

Comment: But that is just it, if it was recording 77fps , but the file header claims it is  60fps , then it plays at 60fps. The players just try to do what they are told, The players also may not understand a 77fps video and play it wrong.  and looks some slow?  did you ever try to play it back at 77fps?  If it was completly failing to record frames, because it is not designed to handle what your throwing at it, then it should instead miss frames , or be faster when played at 60fps

Comment: @Psycogeek i know that, I can edit the video. But I'm asking if is possible to output to one monitor 77 hz and to the second 60 hz in dual view. That was my question.